# Python: reading CSV file line by line, how to detect end?

Tags: python, csv

I read large CSV file (millions of records) by this script. How do I detect the file is at end?

```
import csv
f = open("file.csv", newline='')
csv_reader = csv.reader(f)

while true:
    do something with next(csv_reader)[6]
```

Comment: Depends on how your code is constructed. What you've shown here is not runnable

Answer (score 0):

The `csv.reader` will read the file entirely and store it in the variable which is also an `iterable`. For reading "line by line", you need this:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    do something
```

If you directly want the last line:

```
with open(‘file_name.csv’,’r’) as file: 
    data = file.readlines() 
lastRow = data[-1]
```

This will be quite slow and memory consuming. Alternative is  using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to loop over `csv_reader`, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71234739/4177009). If that is not practical, the [docs for the `next` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) say:

> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its `__next__()` method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

thus giving you two ways of detecting the end.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
csv_reader = pd.read_csv("file.csv", skiprows=2, usecols=[6])
csv_a = csv_reader.to_numpy()
```

this script skips first 2 rows and then imports 6th column only and converts to array

Comment: Mark this itself as answer if it solved your problem ;)